# How can I recall the last region selected in emacs?

Tags: emacs

When I hit "undo" in emacs it undoes the my edit, but I lose the selected region, and I have to go back and reselect it. Is there a way to bind undo so it'll select the last selected region

The best I can come up with was:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-o")
                (lambda()
                  (interactive)
                  (progn (undo)
                          (exchange-point-and-mark)
                          )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [advice](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_212.html) to take what you have and wrap it around `undo`:

```el
(defadvice undo (around reactivate-mark (&optional arg) activate)
  (let ((ma mark-active))
    ad-do-it
    ;; Reactiveate mark if it was active
    (when ma
      (exchange-point-and-mark))))
```

Comment: You should insert a global test-variable like 'undo-remark-region-p' (or a hook call) inside this advice, because the advice extends the function globally, and in some modes probably he does not want this behaviour, etc. It is better to make this behaviour optional, I believe.

Answer (score 34):

You do NOT lose the region. The region remains in the yank-ring.

If you want to re-select it, you can simply call `exchange-point-and-mark`, which is bound by default to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd>.

Comment: This should be the right answer